# Sci-fi movie where a spaceship containing dead aliens is found on Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie

When I was kid saw a movie about a spaceship found on earth containing two dead astronauts. Can only remember parts and my guess is that MAYBE is from the second half of the 70's:

- The dead astronauts were humanoid, in fact -and oddly- human but they didn't have appendix.
- Their eyes were covered by some sort of white? plastic contact lens, the scientist said that maybe was for high speed protection while travelling in space.
- In the spaceship they had recordings with strange characters (sort of Japanese or something)
- The astronauts died when some vessel broke and released poisonous gas (I think).

Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: I wanna thank you all for the answers and specially Hypnosifl; he got the exact title right away. Man, I own you a beer or something xD xD, been looking for this movie for months (no kidding). After reading the sinopsys, it made a lot of sense why they showed it so much on TV in that time. The goverment of the place I come from (a commie country) just love this kind of cover up stories, specially if US related... oh well. In the next days I will watch it again, more than 30 years since the last time :-0 On exchange, will try to help some other people looking for old movies in this site. Regard

Answer (score 8):

This might be [*Hangar 18*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CFHEEVM) from 1980, about a government conspiracy to cover up a crashed flying saucer. Here are the humanoid aliens with pale eyes, though I think they were just supposed to be the natural color rather than contact lenses:

[image: Image of an alien with pale eyes]

The calligraphic alien symbols seen inside the ship:

[image: Image of alien calligraphic script]

### Trailer

In the film, the dead aliens are first seen at 36:05. At 1:02:00 they're talking about the result of the autopsy and they mention they *do* have an appendix, and that this is evidence of a "parallel evolutionary process", but maybe it's possible you misremembered what they said about the appendix. And at 1:17:30 they explain that the aliens were asphyxiated when some glass vials containing "an element similar to potassium cyanide" and some other compounds broke open (due to a collision with an Earth satellite at the beginning of the movie) and created a deadly gas.

Comment: This movie was featured in a very early episode of Mystery Science Theater 3000.  It can be watched here: http://www.club-mst3k.com/19-hangar-18

Answer (score 6):

The description of the 'aliens' puts me in mind of the [aliens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFO_(TV_series)#Aliens) from the Gerry Anderson live-action series [UFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFO_(TV_series)), which had the contact lens removal shown in the [title sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQj_WajKgDY) and also fits the period given though it was a series and not a movie.

From the [script](http://ufoseries.com/scripts/identified.txt) (Mark 172):

> THE DOCTORS GLOVED HANDS WORK ON THE ALIEN'S EYE. THEY MOVE TO SHOW
>   THEY HAVE REMOVED A  PLASTIC COVER FROM THE EYEBALL.

Comment: and I thought the UFO aliens found Earth atmosphere toxic.

Answer (score 2):

Another (admittedly unlikely) guess:
**5,000,000 Years to Earth / Quartermass and the Pit**

> Workers building an extension to the London Underground at Hobbs End
> dig up skeletal remains. Palaeontologist Dr Matthew Roney (James
> Donald) is called in and deduces that they are the remnants of a group
> of apemen over five million years old, more ancient than any previous
> finds. One of Roney's assistants uncovers part of a metallic object.
> ...
>
> When another skeleton is found in an inner chamber, Quatermass and
> Roney realise that the object must also be five million years old.
> Quatermass suspects it is of alien origin, but Roney is certain the
> apemen are terrestrial. ...
>
> An attempt to open a sealed chamber using a Borazon drill fails to
> make any progress. However, a few moments after the drill is stopped,
> a small hole is seen, though the drill operator, Sladden (Duncan
> Lamont), is certain it was not created by his machine. The hole widens
> to reveal the contents: the corpses of three-legged, insectoid
> creatures with horned heads. Roney and Judd work to preserve the
> bodies before they decay. An examination of the creatures' physiology
> suggests they came from the planet Mars.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quatermass_and_the_Pit_%28film%29#Plot

Comment: I think this one is unlikely, since the humanoids they find are only skeletons (so nothing is known about their eyes or appendices), there's no writing inside the ship, and no evidence of death by poisoning.

Comment: Agreed.  My best guess was UFO, but Phil beat me :)

Comment: @Jim2B Funnily enough Quatermass and the Pit was my first thought